# How do I add a banner area in Sphinx?

Tags: python-sphinx

I'm using [Sphinx](http://sphinx-doc.org/) to document [my open source project](http://pneumatic.io/).  I'd like to add an area above the navigation bar with links to the project on GitHub, my project home, etc. The Sphinx home page has pretty much what I want where it has "Home", "Get It", "Docs", "Extend/Develop".

The conf.py file has a ton of options, and then there are themes, templates and more. It seems like it should be simple, but I'm not seeing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I cloned the [Sphinx project on GitHub](https://github.com/sphinx-doc/sphinx) to find the answer.

If you extend a theme, you can add links to the `layout.xml` file. The Sphinx docs have this:

```
{% block header %}
<div class="pageheader">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="{{ pathto('index') }}">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="{{ pathto('install') }}">Get it</a></li>
    <li><a href="{{ pathto('contents') }}">Docs</a></li>
    <li><a href="{{ pathto('develop') }}">Extend/Develop</a></li>
  </ul>
  <div>
    <a href="{{ pathto('index') }}">
      <img src="{{ pathto('_static/sphinxheader.png', 1) }}" alt="SPHINX" />
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
{% endblock %}
```